# Unexpected iterator behavior

Tags: c++, iterator, segmentation-fault

In this loop I call `toString()` method on svg tag's childs. But every time I get Segmentation fault in the first iteration.

```
std::list<Tag*> children;

std::string TagSvg::toString() const{
     if(this->getChildren().empty()) return "<svg/>";

     std::string temp="";
     temp+="<svg>\n";

     for(std::list<Tag*>::const_iterator it=this->getChildren().begin(); it != this->getChildren().end(); ++it){
          temp+=(*it)->toString();
     }

     temp+="</svg>\n";

     return temp;
}


std::list<Tag*> Tag::getChildren() const{
     return children;
}
```

As you can see in this image, SVG Tag has childs, it should call `toString()` on TagG in first iteration, but it doesn't even set iterator correctly as you can see, because TagG has 2 childs and that dereferenced iterator has 0 childs and weird attributes. Could someone show me what I got wrong? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: please paste code for your function getChildren. does it return by value?

Comment: Can you try changing this " temp+=(*it)->toString();" into "temp+=it->toString();" this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably your function `getChildren` returns by value and then

```
std::list<Tag*>::const_iterator it=this->getChildren().begin();
```

and

```
it != this->getChildren().end();
```

points to the **begin** and the **end** of **different containers.** From your edit it is clear this is exactly this case, so please do a change:

```
std::list<Tag*>& Tag::getChildren() const{
     return children;
}
```

or do it like:

```
std::list<Tag*> children = this->getChildren(); //now you ensure you work on
                                                //a single and the same container
for(std::list<Tag*>::const_iterator it=children.begin();
                                         it != this->children.end(); ++it){
          temp+=(*it)->toString();
     }
```